# How can I capture the output of a webpack build as a string before it is written to disk?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

There seems to be no `output` option in webpack to write the output as a string, either to a nodejs `Buffer` or to `stdout`. Googling has yielded nothing promising. Is this possible, via either configuration or 3rd-party-module?

Comment: Is the stat object enough for what you need ? https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api

Comment: I looked at that. My main goal is to avoid the thrash of writing a file to disk, and then immediately reading it in order to get its string contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, the only way I see to accomplish this would be to monkey-patch webpack's [`NodeOutputFileSystem.writeFile`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/f5a5edd78d15436f1fa3a1deb0fe0cc2b67c563e/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem.js) to capture the string contents.

I ended up using raw babeljs instead of webpack to get the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can [write to an in-memory filesystem and read from it after compilation](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#custom-file-systems):

```js
const compiler = webpack({ / options / });
const outputFileSystem = new webpack.MemoryOutputFileSystem()
compiler.outputFileSystem = outputFileSystem;
compiler.run((err, stats) => {
  // Read the output later:
  const content = outputFileSystem.readFileSync('...');
});
```

This involves calling webpack via its Node API, but the same may also be accomplished entirely in `webpack.config.json` by [creating a custom webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/) that changes the compiler’s `outputFileSystem` on `apply`.

Comment: `webpack.MemoryOutputFileSystem` doesn't seem to exist anymore. Just follow the link though and use `memfs` as suggested.